# Chainring just don't know when to let go

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, drivetrain, noise, wear

My chain needed to be replaced for half a year ago and I've finally replaced it. But after replacing it, I've notice a lot of clicking noise from the chainring area. and when I go check it, I saw the chain sticking to the bottom side of the chainring while I'm pedaling.

I went back to the shop to tell the owner what's wrong, he just say it's the friction from the chain and the chainring, it will be gone if I just ride the bike for a month or so. Now the noise is still there but not as loud as before, but is there something I should have done that doesn't require to wear off the bike chainring? Cuz I bought the chainring a few months ago.

Update: my old chain needs to be replaced but I kept on using it for almost a year already, not sure if that's the reason why.

Here is a pic of the chainring.
[image]

Comment: Normally this would indicate that your chainring is worn out, but if it's relatively new then I'd suspect that the chain is too long.

Comment: The shop owner ask if I wanted the chain to be shorter, and I said yes. So the chain being too long is not the reason.

Comment: You rode on a worn out chain for a year?  Yes - that has probably caused knockon damage in your cassette, chainrings and maybe even jockey wheels.

Comment: From the picture, the chainring doesn't look badly worn (although can't always tell visually).  I'd start by giving the chain a thorough clean (manufacturers coating can be sticky).  It also looks like a narrow/wide chainring, which have their benefits, but are more likely to give chain suck

Answer (score 5):

This is called chain suck. One possible reason is worn chainrings.

In the question it is mentioned that the rings were used with worn out chain. This wears out chainrings quickly.

Comment: The shape of the teeth will tell. Shark teeth point to a worn-out ring.

Comment: Is it okay if I don't replace the chainring?

Comment: Your decision. Chainrings are soft, maybe it will wear to less noisy shape.

Comment: I will add a picture of the chainring and see what you guys think.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a narrow-wide chainring for a 1x driveline. Is that what you have? Otherwise maybe the wide shoulders are too wide for the chain. Also, judging from the marks on the spider it looks like you may have had it mounted on the front of the spider in the past instead of in the back?

Comment: Simpler explication is he has put the chain on so the narrow is on the wide tooth.

Comment: I don't know what's a "spider", and I'm positive that I have put the chain in the right spot

Comment: The thing that the chain ring is bolted to. Maybe the chain ring should be in front instead of in the back, but that probably wouldn't cause the problem you have.